# Retrieving the last values from the database - should the results be sorted?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

The database stores the currency exchange rate on a given day. Each day, one currency exchange value is collected and stored in the database as:

| ID (int, AI) | VALUE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 20.01.2021 |
| 2 | 2.7 | 21.01.2021 |
| 3 | 2.6 | 22.01.2021 |

If I would like to calculate the average exchange rate from the last 10 days, should I first sort the data by date and only retrieve the last 10 records when downloading the data, or is it enough to download the last 10 records from the database without sorting?

Comment: SQL Tables represent unordered sets. So you need to sort.

Comment: Probably depends on exact RDBMS you're using but none of the ones I used have any written/documented order in which they return rows without explicit order requested.

Comment: No, does not depend except on VERY special things - unless you order, you are at the mercy of query optimization. It is undefined and any different order for whatever reason - is valid. You basically rely on undocumented behavior. This is essential basic SQL: Want an order, query with an order.

Comment: Why is this question tagged c#, or asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tables (and table expressions such as views and CTEs) in SQL represent *unordered sets*.** To get data in a particular order, you *must* specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

In fairly generic SQL you can do

```
SELECT AVG(VALUE) AS AverageRate
FROM (
    SELECT VALUE
    FROM YourTable AS t
    ORDER BY Id DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
) AS t
```

In some RDBMSs, instead of `OFFSET` `FETCH`, you use either `LIMIT` or `TOP` to achieve the same effect. You still need `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Charlieface, thank you for your answer. I noticed that if I add a new value to a table and the identifier is, for example, of the Guid type, it is added to the table in alphabetical order. However, if the table key is of the int AI type, will there be any possibility that the newly added record will not end up at the end of the table? If, in the case of int AI keys, the new element always goes to the end of the table, why sort the data when retrieving it, if it is known that the last 30 records will always be the latest records?

Comment: There is no "end of the table", a table represents an unordered set. It is certainly possible that you have an index on that column and that most of the time it will read it in index order, but there is **absolutely no guarantee** that this will always be the case. For example, it may use a different index, or it may parallelize, or it may hash join it with something else. If you want it in a particular order you **must** specify. Bear in mind that if you have an index then no sorting actually takes place, the server will just start at the end and read backwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do in SQL Server database

```
SELECT TOP 10 AVG(VALUE) AS AverageRate
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Concept should be same in other relational databases.

Comment: 1.That's not what OP wants, 2.The DBMS is still unknown

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Why did you add `NOLOCK`, do you know that it can give you completely incorrect data? You did not even have the correct syntax. This is also not going to work as OP wants, because only one `AVG` value is returned, unless you use `GROUP BY`

Comment: What was wrong with the syntax? Can you please tell? OP has mentioned that he wants average. @Charlieface

Comment: `FROM YourTable WITH (NOLOCK)` would have been correct syntax if you *really* needed `NOLOCK`, the other syntax is deprecated (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)). This query anyway gets incorrect results because `TOP` is calculated after the aggregation on the whole table. You need a CTE or derived table here

Comment: Without braces also works, I use it very frequent. I have run the query in Sal server and it works as expected @Charlieface

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in both ways.

If you're using SQL with Dapper or ADO.NET, then you can write a query.
It should be sorted if you need the last 10 values

```
SELECT TOP 10 AVG(your value) AS average
FROM YourCurrencyExchangeTable
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

If you're using EntityFrameWorkCore, you can write

```
var avg = db.yourDbContext
        .Where(c => c.Date >= tenDaysAgoDate)
        .Average(c => c.yourValue)
```

I hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to sort first ( on date) and then get the last 10 values, so you're on the right track.

Comment: Hey, I see you are new on SO, welcome! Your answers to this question does not provide much information, so it would be better posted as a comment! If you can find some info on how to write better answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), hope it helps!